# Choose Nodes within another Node

Tags: 7, nodes

This is something I've struggled with for a long time in Drupal. I'm guessing it's a relatively easy answer but I haven't been able to find an elegant solution. Here's the problem:

Let's say I have an e-comm site with Categories, Coupons and Products(all are CCK content types). Each Category can have any number of Products and Coupons. I'd like the ability to have a menu within my Category node that will allow me to select any of the existing Product and Coupon nodes. Also, not necessary but ideally I'd like the ability to change the order of Products/Coupons within the Category.

Is this possible? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Views?
http://drupal.org/project/views It will allow you to filter and sort your nodes, taxonomy etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have. The issue I had with Views is that I can only Filter by content type. So, I'd need to display all Products. I can add a filter for the node name, but this becomes very tedious with many Products. I'm thinking there must be an easier way...

Comment: Could you expand on this a little: "I'd like the ability to have a menu within my Category node that will allow me to select any of the existing Product and Coupon nodes."  Do you have a sample screenshot of what you're trying to achieve from an already live site or could you just describe what exactly the ideal final functionality would be?

Answer (score 0):

May be you're better of creating a vocabulary for your categories. This way you can filter for vocabulary terms in views.